# How to install NVidia card driver (laptop)?

Tags: nvidia

I'm new to linux, and my problem is that when i pass with the cursor hover certain things(like the bar on the top) it starts glitching. I read around the internet that i need to install nvidia card driver, i did that but once installed when i tried to run the OS nothing appeared, black screen. Then i just did a fresh installation of the OS. I tried also to install bumblebee but nothing changed, so want to ask you if there is any way to install this driver and stop my cursor glitching.

Answer (score 4):

I don't recommend you to add any PPA to install your graphics driver. If you want a stable system, stick to the official repos.

You could use bumblebee to switch between graphics card for some apps, but it's harder to configure than `nvidia-prime` so I don't recommend bumblebee unless you want a fully open source installation (both the nvidia driver and nvidia-prime are proprietary software). If this is the case, I'll update my answer. But for now, I'll explain a more basic config:

First Delete everything related to bumblebee:

```
sudo apt remove bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus
```

Check what drivers are avaliable for your system:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices | grep -o nvidia-[[:digit:]]*
```

Then install the one you want (replace XXX with the correct number):

```
sudo apt install nvidia-XXX
```

In case you have Optimus Technology you would also want to install this:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-prime
```

In case you want to fine tune your settings, is recommended to install `nvidia-settings` as well:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-settings
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi first check wich nvidia-driver you need for 0.4 Loki wich is based on Ubuntu 16.04 there are:

Current official release: `nvidia-370` (370.28)

Current long-lived branch release: `nvidia-367` (367.57)

For GeForce 8 and 9 series GPUs use `nvidia-340` (340.98)

For GeForce 6 and 7 series GPUs use `nvidia-304` (304.132)

First add the PPA:

`sudo apt-get install software-properties-common`

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`

`sudo apt-get update`

Get bumblebee via ppa:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:neon1ks/bumblebee`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install bumblebee`

Then install the driver with bumblebee and nvidia-setting the config tool from nvidia heres an example:

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-370 nvidia-settings bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus`

Here is a howto install nvidia-drivers with the terminal:

[How to install the latest Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus)

Comment: Bumblebee is not an old version. Is a completely different way of working with Optimus laptops.  The main difference is that with `bumblebee` you can choose what apps you want to open with the nvidia card whereas with `nvidia-prime` you can only use one graphics card at the time (that's why you have to logout everytime you want to switch)

Comment: Sorry for the mistake you're right, I didn't knew that `bumblebee` is still maintained ...because the last post on http://bumblebee-project.org/ is from 2013.. you're right that prime and bumblebee are different ways of working with Optimus laptops.

Comment: https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed

Last closed issue was from some days ago. I'm pretty sure they keep maintaining it.

Comment: Again sorry for my mistake

Comment: It's fine, no need to apologize :)

Answer (score -1):

First add the PPA:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-properties-gtk
```

Then go to Application in the top left corner of the screen and search for "software" and select "software & applications". Then go to the "Additional Drivers" tab and select Nvidia drivers. Apply the change and restart the computer. You might need to restart AND login to the computer once to remove any errors that might occur, I had a black left screen but then I logged in and it fixed itself after about 8 seconds.